# Why can't I create a symlink to a directory at the same level as that directory?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, symbolic-link

I have a directory called `Foo`. I want a symlink to it, on the same level as it, called `foo`.

`ln -s Foo foo` creates a symlink *in* `Foo` pointing back to itself.

```
$ mkdir lntmp && cd lntmp
$ mkdir Foo
$ touch Foo/file
$ ln -s Foo foo
$ tree
.
└── Foo
    ├── Foo -> Foo
    └── file

1 directory, 2 files
```

What I want to achieve is

```
$ tree
.
└── foo -> Foo
└── Foo
    └── file
```

Comment: Did you try a hardlink (without -s) instead of a symlink?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It turns out hardlinks don't work on directories, only files.

Comment: According to the [manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/ln.1.html) the option `-d` (`--directory`) creates hardlinks to directories...

Comment: Sadly that option isn't present on macOS (which I should've been more explicit about using)

Comment: Odd, considering how macOS is the only one which _does_ allow directory hardlinks (for Time Machine purposes)... Most other systems and filesystems don't, to avoid infinitely nested directories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using macOS (according to question tags), then your disk is probably using a case-insensitive filesystem – so `foo` and `Foo` are identical and you cannot have both in the same directory.

Instead of a symlink, try `mkdir foo` or `touch foo` and see what you get.